# How do I refresh in Firefox and preserve breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, firefox, breakpoints, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-aurora

I am debugging javascript in Firefox Aurora Developer Tools. I set a breakpoint in a javascript file, and refreshed the page, after which all my breakpoints went away.

How do I preserve breakpoints in Firefox developer tools when I refresh the page?

Comment: What version of Firefox has this bug?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 28.0a2 (2014-01-29) [nightly channel]. I've loaded up a profile with no extensions, and still see the same behavior. Breakpoints are listed in both places (line# under the file, and blue-dot inside of the file); black-box settings are honored. But breakpoints need to be manually set (or use the `debugger;` directive) after a refresh. PITA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a regression; breakpoints should stay active across page refreshes.

Can you share the code you are working with (or a minimal test case) and give some steps to reproduce the lost breakpoints?

Answer (score 1):

The breakpoints stay highlighted across refreshes, but fail to break.. restarting firefox occasionally will let it work, but it's basically a bug. Been working with this all day, the breakpoints seem to be basically broken.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug. But I'm not sure if it works properly with Aurora