# Live JavaScript edit & compile - Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

Firefox has recently released a new "Firefox Developer Edition" providing all development features natively.

I always use chrome for my developer needs and thought of giving it a try. Searched through but found no way to edit JavaScript live & re-compile the script like in Chrome.

Of course, there is scratchpad but it's not changing the existing script and IMHO is no different then executing a script in console.

Is Firefox still way behind Chrome developer tools ? Or I missed how to live-edit javascript in Firefox ?

References :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firefox devtools are actually in standard Firefox too.

**Is Firefox still way behind Chrome developer tools ?**

No, Firefox devtool is way ahead of Chrome in a few ways, it has web-audio tab, canvas tab, shader editor for webgl, a style editor that lets you easily click to show/disable stylesheets, etc.

**I missed how to live-edit javascript in Firefox ?**
Unfortunately the JS debugger is definitely way behind Chrome. Not only does it not have live editing, even basic [handling of callbacks](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=977972) can be problematic at the moment and there are many [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752048/) [of](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=947144) [bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925786) (Chrome has devtools bugs too, but are not usually as noticeable).

Answer (score 0):

Use the ScratchPad. For example:

[image: Drag and Drop disable via ScratchPad]

**References**

- [Scratchpad - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad)
- [Firefox Developer Tools - Scratchpad - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt7DZACyClM)

Comment: Scratchpad will be deprecated soon.